# Regex: Is it possible to use "|" for only part of match pattern?

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to do something like the following:

```
re.match(r'someArbLongRegex{option1|option2}anotherArbLongRegex', line)
```

as opposed to having to do:

```
re.match(r'someArbLongRegexoption1anotherArbLongRegex|someArbLongRegexoption2anotherArbLongRegex', line)
```

Basically instead of `|` applying to the whole regex pattern I just want it to apply to one small part of the regex pattern.

Comment: dealing with | when searching was a real pain (even with escaping it) so there is a chance a similar question is out there that I just missed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use (?:option1|option2)

```
re.match(r'someArbLongRegex(?:option1|option2)anotherArbLongRegex', line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just use parenthesis.

```
re.match(r'someArbLongRegex((option1)|(option2))anotherArbLongRegex', line)
```

Sometimes, depending on the data, you know that option1 and option2 won't both be in 'line', and at least 1 of them will. Then you can just do this:

```
re.match(r'(someArbLongRegex)((option1)?(option2)?)anotherArbLongRegex', line)
```

Comment: I went with Felipe's solution since it doesn't mess up capture groups